# how to call and use asyntask independent class when button in baseadapter class clicked

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, download

i have been searching a while and i came across so many solution about base adapter and asyntask but did not solve my problem, so i think my case is a bit different.
           i have a project that has independent asyncTask class and baseadapter class, In side base adapter class there is the button linked to the list view so 
           When button in the listview clicked  call and excute the asyncTask for mp3 downloading process.
           But the  problem is when button in the lisview clicked progress bar appear like it start downloading and disapper before start downloading process,
           I think the problem is on how to call this asyncTask class in base adapter class.
               Any idea  on what , where and how to fix, I will be so glad to work it out. Am real new to android.
here is the code:

baseadapter class

```
   public class DisplayAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
     private Context mContext;
     //list fields to be displayed
      private ArrayList<String> stafid;
       private ArrayList<String> nama;
      private ArrayList<String> jbt;

public DisplayAdapter(Context c, ArrayList<String> stafid, ArrayList<String> nama, ArrayList<String> jbt) {
    this.mContext = c;
    //transfer content from database to temporary memory
    this.stafid = stafid;
    this.nama = nama;
    this.jbt = jbt;
}


public DisplayAdapter(Context context){
    this.mContext=context;
}

public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return stafid.size();
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

public View getView(final int pos, View child, final ViewGroup parent) {
    Holder mHolder;
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
    if (child == null) {
        layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        child = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.listcell, null);
        mHolder = new Holder();
        mHolder.button1= (Button) child.findViewById(R.id.misa1);
        mHolder.button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // call DownloadFileAsync 
           String fileURL = "http://XXXXXXX/sound/audio.mp3";
            new DownloadFileAsync(mContext).execute(fileURL);
            }
        });
        child.setTag(mHolder);
    } else {
    mHolder = (Holder) child.getTag();
    }
    //transfer to TextView in screen
    mHolder.txtstafid.setText(stafid.get(pos));
    mHolder.txtnama.setText(nama.get(pos));
    mHolder.txtjbt.setText(jbt.get(pos));
    return child;
     }
public class Holder {
    TextView txtstafid;
    TextView txtnama;
    TextView txtjbt;
    Button button1;
}
   }
```

AsycTast class

```
 public class DownloadFileAsync extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    public static final int DIALOG_DOWNLOAD_PROGRESS = 0;
  private ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
   private Context context;
   public DownloadFileAsync(Context context)
{
    this.context = context;
    mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
    mProgressDialog.setMessage("Downloading file..");
    mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
    mProgressDialog.setMax(100);
    mProgressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
    mProgressDialog.setCancelable(true);
}
@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
    mProgressDialog.show();
      }
/**
 * Downloading file in background thread
 * */
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... f_url) {
    int count;
    try {
        URL url = new URL(f_url[0]);
        URLConnection conection = url.openConnection();
        conection.connect();
        // this will be useful so that you can show a tipical 0-100% progress bar
        int lenghtOfFile = conection.getContentLength();
        // download the file
        InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream(), 8192);
        // Output stream
        OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream("/sdcard/audio.mp3");
        byte data[] = new byte[1024];
        long total = 0;
        while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
            total += count;
            // publishing the progress....
            // After this onProgressUpdate will be called
            publishProgress(""+(int)((total*100)/lenghtOfFile));
            // writing data to file
            output.write(data, 0, count);
           }
        // flushing output
        output.flush();
        // closing streams
        output.close();
        input.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
    }
    return null;
    }
/**
 * Updating progress bar
 * */
protected void onProgressUpdate(String... progress) {
    // setting progress percentage
    mProgressDialog.setProgress(Integer.parseInt(progress[0]));
   }
/**
 * After completing background task
 * Dismiss the progress dialog
 * **/
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
    // dismiss the dialog after the file was downloaded
    mProgressDialog.dismiss();
    // Displaying downloaded image into image view
    // Reading image path from sdcard

}
   }
```

To make it more clear i tried to use the same concept in this activity and it work so fine

```
Public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private static String fileURL = "http://XXXXXXXXX/sound/audio.mp3";
@Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
     {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Button button= (Button)findViewById(R.id.download);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            startDownload();
        }
    });
}

private void startDownload() {
    new DownloadFileAsync(this).execute(fileURL);
}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`setOnClickListener` should be outside of if and else

```
if (child == null) {
    layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    child = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.listcell, null);
    mHolder = new Holder();
    mHolder.button1= (Button) child.findViewById(R.id.misa1);

    child.setTag(mHolder);
} else {
mHolder = (Holder) child.getTag();
}
//transfer to TextView in screen
mHolder.txtstafid.setText(stafid.get(pos));
mHolder.txtnama.setText(nama.get(pos));
mHolder.txtjbt.setText(jbt.get(pos));

mHolder.button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // call DownloadFileAsync 
       String fileURL = "http://XXXXXXX/sound/audio.mp3";
        new DownloadFileAsync(mContext).execute(fileURL);
        }
    });

return child;
 }
```

Comment: thanks @Ajay it now works, i had to uninstall the app from my mobile phone and run it again

Comment: @F.joel I am glad to help you.

Comment: @F.joel do you use Instant Run, if yes than this can happen, you need to uninstall sometime.

Comment: Thanks for your advice @AJay